# Getting User from List Item

Tags: 2013, powershell, user

I've checked a few other articles on this but can't find an answer to this: I have a list which contains a User column and I want to get hold of the User to use in site permissioning. The problem I have when i retrieve the user details is that it returns a numeric value along with the user name, so it doesn't recognise the account later on. So getting the item from the list:

```
 $PrimaryOwnerItem = $_["Primary Owner"];
 $PrimaryOwnerItem
```

returns value:

```
 16;#User Name
```

Trying to assign the user to an object doesn't work because it doesn't recognise the User, presumably because of the "16;" which prefixes the name:

```
$PrimaryOwnerObject = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($RequestWeb, $_["Primary Owner"])
```

Any ideas what the "16;" (and possibly the "#") relates to and how I can just retrieve the username? Its the same if I use the email address in the list, I still get "16;#user_name@domain.com".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s how SharePoint Stores the values in the user field internally. the number is the userID of the user, followed by ",#" and the Display Name.

That´s because technically the SPUserField is a Lookup-Field, linked to the "User Information List".

Try to cast the value of $_["Primary Owner"] to SPFieldUserValue directly, because what you see in the Output is just the "ToString()" Representation of the object

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I cast directly to the SPFieldUservalue other than in the code above?

Otherwise, could I trim it after "#" ? Would that be reliable?

Comment: What Informatoin do you expect to get? AccountName, DisplayName?... If you´re happe with the Information in the string, you could do it by converting it to a SPFieldLookupvalue (what it is basically) by using New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($_["Primary Owner"]). From that Object you could then use the LookupId (if needed) or the lookupvalue, which is the the Display Name of the user in the case of an SPUserField

Comment: Thanks very much Leopold, all working now. This is how I've done it:

     $PrimaryOwnerLookup = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($_["Primary Owner"])
     $PrimaryOwnerObject = $RequestWeb.EnsureUser($PrimaryOwnerLookup.lookupvalue)
     $PrimaryOwner = $PrimaryOwnerObject.UserLogin

Comment: Argh, this doesn't work when there are duplicate user names...